# How can I place an image that goes from `.col-md-4` to the end of the screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I place an image that goes from end of `.col-md-4` to the end of the screen?

Here is what I have to do by design - red lines are `.container` boundaries, text is aligned to the left, and on the right is an image (or slider). I can't do `.col-md-8` since the image needs to go as far as the screen is wide.
Can I combine `.container` and `.container` fluid somehow? What would you suggest? Image must be visible full width across all desktop sizes.

[image]
I currently did this with position absolute but this way the image is cut out and this is not desirable. https://codepen.io/ivan-topi/pen/pGYYjj
If I remove `position: relative` from `.row` and place it on `.content` then I can position image nicely with `right: 0` to the end of the screen, but in that case I am not sure how can I position it without overlapping text on the left?

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id odio assumenda nobis recusandae voluptates itaque possimus provident libero et earum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1300x450">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;
}
.row {
  position: relative;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.img-wrapper {
  left: 435px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Not very understand your question. Is any section's(left/right) width fixed? If the resolution is 1024X768, what's the expected behavior of the right section(image)? The image in your example is larger than 1024 px, and you want it be full width visible, how's that possible?

Comment: It is an example since the image should be big enough for large screens. Either way, image should always go from text to the end of the screen and shrink accordingly, but always remain fully visible. Same thing applies for 992px width or 1600px wide screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider negative margin while using `col-md-8`. The trick is to add the amount space on the right as a negative margin to the container inside `col-md-8` to create the overflow you want:

```css
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
img {
  width:100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .negative {
    margin-right: calc((720px - 100vw)/2 - 15px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .negative {
    margin-right: calc((960px - 100vw)/2 - 15px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .negative {
    margin-right: calc((1140px - 100vw)/2 - 15px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id odio assumenda nobis recusandae voluptates itaque possimus provident libero et earum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="negative">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1300x450" class="d-block">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, you need this:

```
 <div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 p-0 d-flex align-items-center">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id odio assumenda nobis recusandae voluptates itaque possimus provident libero et earum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 p-0">

        <img class="img-fluid"  src="https://via.placeholder.com/1300x450">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And from `.img-wrapper` remove `position:absolute` and `left: 435px;`

Check it here: https://codepen.io/gionic/pen/QYoPqq

I hope it helps you.

Comment: The problem is that text should be inside .container

Comment: It is, inside container-fluid > row > col-md-4. Have you check the link in codepen?

Comment: you have a redundant img-wrapper in your post here.

Comment: I have, it is inside .container-fluid, not inside .container. Text should not be blown outside of regular Bootstrap .container sizes